# Ruby's redis gem seemingly returns integers in error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I've implemented a library wrapper around Ruby's Redis gem.

There are times when I call CacheManager.get("key") and it somehow triggers an error that gets caught in the rescue. The error looks like this: `undefined method 'join' for 20325:Integer (NoMethodError)`. The obvious fix is just to call `.to_s`  on the error.message, but I'd love to understand what's happening and why Redis is returning an integer as its error message.

```
class CacheManager
  def self.get(k, default_value = nil)
    begin
      $redis_pool.with { |conn| conn.get(k) } || default_value
    rescue => error
      Rails.logger.error([error.message] + error.backtrace).join($/)
      default_value
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the error is raised on this line:

```
Rails.logger.error([error.message] + error.backtrace).join($/)
```

It is not Redis or the exception raise by the `redis` gem that returns an integer leading this line to raise `undefined method 'join' for 20325:Integer (NoMethodError)`.

It is `Rails.logger.error` returning an integer and then calling `join` on that integer. The return value of that method depends on your logger configuration and version.

When reformatting that line, the issue in that line becomes more obvious:

```
lines = [error.message] + error.backtrace
Rails.logger.error(lines).join($/)
```

To fix this issue, you need to fix the parentheses to ensure that you call `join` on the array you want to join, instead of the logger call, like this:

```
lines = [error.message] + error.backtrace
Rails.logger.error(lines.join($/))
```

Or

```
Rails.logger.error([error.message].concat(error.backtrace).join($/))
```

Comment: Dumb mistake on my part. Thank you!